# Should I close or delete my duplicate question?

Tags: support, status-completed, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I asked a [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/22665/2395) which turned out to be a duplicate (I haven't found it before, and I agree it is a duplicate).

Should I delete the question? But the user who [answered](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/22666/2395) will loose some of his reputation, he spent some time on this, and I wouldn't like to to delete his answer as well, it was not his fault.

*or*

Should I vote for close my own question?

*or*

Do nothing?

Comment: I'd say close and let it be.

Comment: After someone has answered, I thought you couldn't delete your own question unilaterally. I guess you could still vote for deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A moderator has the capability of merging two questions, so what is normally done in this circumstance I believe is to first close the question as a dup and then flag the question and request a moderator perform a merger.

I think I will take this as such a request. After looking them both over, I concurr that they are asking the same thing, and will perform both actions as requested.

```
Beginning merge of question.Id = 22665 into question.Id = 15528 

Moved 1 answers to master 
Moved 0 comments to master 
Moved 0 favorite votes to master 
Master now has 4 active answers 
Master now has 9 active comments 

Master now has 0 favorites 
Successful merge
```

I would highly suggest Alex go look over his answer in its new home, to verify comfort that it fits there as currently worded. I've had a bad experience in the past with this on other stacks (although in that case IMHO the questions were **not** identical, and should never have been merged).

Comment: Oh, and as a protip, I don't believe you lose your rep if the question you answered is closed. In fact, I believe you still get the +25 if the author goes in *after closure* and accepts your answer, which they often do in a fit of pique.